# алгоритм std::move

Tags: c++

Испортит ли эта инструкция данные в файле?

```
std::ifstream in("in.txt");
std::ofstream out("out.txt");

std::move(
  std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
  std::istream_iterator<int>(),
  std::ostream_iterator<int>(out)
);
```

Comment: Эм.. А `std::move` точно принимает 3 аргумента?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Речь очевидно идет о `std::move` из `<algorithm>`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move

Comment: @AnT, ёлки.. ну кто додумался одинаково назвать методы. Я про другой [`std::move`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) подумал... UPDATE: А, разобрался, наверное - он тот move внутри вызывает...

Answer (score 6):

Нет, конечно, данные в файле не испортятся (если речь идет о *читаемом* файле `in`).

Отличие алгоритма `std::move` от, скажем, алгоритма `std::copy` заключается только в том, что операция, применяемая к каждой паре соответствующих элементов диапазонов, это

```
*dst_iterator = std::move(*src_iterator);
```

а не просто

```
*dst_iterator = *src_iterator;
```

И поведение алгоритма `std::move` в данном случае будет зависеть от поведения этого выражения для `dst_iterator` типа `std::ostream_iterator<int>`.

Оператор `*` в `std::ostream_iterator` - это no-op, просто возвращающий ссылку на сам итератор, следовательно все зависит только от поведения `std::ostream_iterator<>::operator=` в данном контексте. А он существует только в одной форме

```
ostream_iterator &operator=(const T &value);
```

Т.е. даже в присутствии `std::move` вызваться будет все равно "обычный" оператор присваивания (тот же самый, который вызывался бы в `std::copy`) и поведение алгоритма `std::move` ничем не будет отличаться от поведения алгоритма `std::copy`.

Отдельно стоит заметить, что оператор присваивания в этом контексте, какие бы формы он ни предоставлял, все равно уже не имеет никакой возможности физически доступиться до исходного файла и как-то "испортить" его. Причем эта возможность отсечена уже на уровне `std::istream_iterator`.

Answer (score 3):

Итератор `std::istream_iterator<int>(in)` считывает данные из файла. Его работа совершенно никак не зависит от того, в какой функции или алгоритме он вызывается. То есть этот итератор ничего не знает о том, где он вызывается, вызывается ли он в алгоритме `std::move` или в каком-нибудь ином алгоритме.  Он обеспечивает получение копии объекта, считанного из потока с помощью оператора `operator >>`.

Более того, так как фундаментальные типы не имеют конструкторов, то есть ни конструктора копирования, ни конструктора перемещения, то при копировании объекта с исходным объектом ничего не происходит.  Поэтому более логично вместо алгоритма `std::move`, который в данном контексте не несет никакой семантической нагрузки, использовать алгоритм `std::copy`.